# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to understand `<any>` element in xsd. I had two xsds.

**Book Catalogue.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="BookCatalogue">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Book" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Author" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Date" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Publisher" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Reviewer.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Reviewer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Name">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="First" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="Last" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>



</xs:schema>
```

But if i validate the below xml based on above xsd, i am getting **cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'p:Reviewer'.** error.  Does both xsd file should not be in same namespace?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pr:BookCatalogue xmlns:pr="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com AddRequest.xsd ">
    <pr:Book>
        <pr:Title>pr:Title</pr:Title>
        <pr:Author>pr:Author</pr:Author>
        <pr:Date>pr:Date</pr:Date>
        <pr:ISBN>pr:ISBN</pr:ISBN>
        <pr:Publisher>pr:Publisher</pr:Publisher>
        <p:Reviewer xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com Children.xsd ">
            <p:Name>
                <p:First>p:First</p:First>
                <p:Last>p:Last</p:Last>
            </p:Name>
        </p:Reviewer>
    </pr:Book>
</pr:BookCatalogue>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options...

**Option One: If you *do not* want to have to have the definition of `p:Reviewer` present**, add `processContents="lax"` to your `xs:any` element:

```
      <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0"  processContents="lax"/>
```

Per [XML Schema Part 0: Primer Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#any):

> The lax value of the processContents attribute instructs an XML
>   processor to validate the element content on a can-do basis: It will
>   validate elements and attributes for which it can obtain schema
>   information, but it will not signal errors for those it cannot obtain
>   any schema information.

See also [XML Validation in Java: processContents=“lax” seems not to work correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820774/xml-validation-in-java-processcontents-lax-seems-not-to-work-correctly).

You should also carefully adjust your `xsi:schemaLocation` values to point to the actual filename of each XSD for each namespace in play.  Here is your XML instance with the changes that I made:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pr:BookCatalogue
    xmlns:pr="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:p="http://www.w3schools.com/1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com BookCatalogue.xsd http://www.w3schools.com/1 Reviewer.xsd">
    <pr:Book>
        <pr:Title>pr:Title</pr:Title>
        <pr:Author>pr:Author</pr:Author>
        <pr:Date>pr:Date</pr:Date>
        <pr:ISBN>pr:ISBN</pr:ISBN>
        <pr:Publisher>pr:Publisher</pr:Publisher>
        <p:Reviewer>
            <p:Name>
                <p:First>p:First</p:First>
                <p:Last>p:Last</p:Last>
            </p:Name>
        </p:Reviewer>
    </pr:Book>
</pr:BookCatalogue>
```

Note: Make sure that the `targetNamespace` in Review.xsd matches what's declared for it in BookCatalogue.xml's `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute.

**Option Two: If you *do* want to insist that the definition of `p:Reviewer` be present**, just make the above changes to be sure that Review.xsd can be found per the `xsi:schemaLocation` mechanism.  No `processContents` setting is required; it defaults to `strict`.

Comment: Thanks. But why error came before and not now? what that means.

Comment: Originally the processor could not find the definition of `p:Review` and was obligated to complain because `xs:any/@processContents` defaults to `strict`.  You should be sure that your `schemaLocation` settings are proper before risking **masking the problem** by using the `lax` setting of `processContents`.