# How to declare any content inside element with XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

How to declare that inside tag `<mytag>` can anything be contain, including arbitrary unknown tags and plain text.

**UPDATE**

I have declared the following way

```
<xs:group name="mygroup">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="mytag">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any/>       
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>   
    </xs:choice>
</xs:group>
```

But unfortunately, parser raises error on some tag inside `<mytag>`

> [2013-11-28 19:47:29,732] WARN: Error parsing "file:myfile":
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'innertag'.
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>   declaration can be found for element 'innertag'.

I want any `<innertag>` accepted.

**UPDATE 2**

The following declaration worked:

```
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any namespace="##any" minOccurs="0"  processContents="lax"/>        
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
```

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102397/cvc-complex-type-2-4-c-the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can seems related.

Comment: If you still need help with this, please include the smallest, complete XSD and XML files that exhibit the issue.  Thanks.

Comment: If you've found the answer you should post it as an answer to your own question, rather than editing the question.

Comment: @SirCrispalot I am not very experienced in XSD, may be someone will post more complete answer.